# Bulk loading in Hbase with compression and encoding

Tags: hadoop, compression, hbase, bulk-load

I am trying to bulk load some network-data into an Hbase table. My mapper emits ImmutableBytesWritable, KeyValue pairs. I declare a pre-splitted table wher the column families have compression set to SNAPPY and Data Block Encoding set to PREFIX_TREE (`hcd.setCompressionType(Algorithm.SNAPPY);` and `hcd.setDataBlockEncoding(DataBlockEncoding.PREFIX_TREE);`).

Subsequently I use HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(job, table) which should generate the HFiles for me. However, I run into the following error.

`14/12/14 12:23:04 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 80%
14/12/14 12:23:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1416932815472_0065_r_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.encoding.HFileBlockDefaultEncodingContext.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/io/compress/Compression$Algorithm;Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/io/encoding/DataBlockEncoding;[B)V`

Am I not configuring the compression properly ? I suspected that HFileOutputFormat2 may not have support for compression/encoding but I get the same error when they are disabled. Any ideas what's going on ?